# Using settings in scratch org definition file get knowledge cannot be disabled error

Tags: salesforcedx

As Spring 19 is approaching, OrgPreferences is going to be expired soon for scratch org definition files. So I am working on updating it to metadata settings style. Others work okay, but I fail to disable salesforce knowledge when creating new scratch orgs. I am getting the error message:

> Knowledge  Once enabled, Salesforce Knowledge can't be disabled.

My definition files is as below:

```
{
    "orgName": "Spot Asia",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features" : [
        "PersonAccounts",
        "AuthorApex",
        "ServiceCloud",
        "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
        "LightningSalesConsole",
        "LightningServiceConsole",
        "MultiCurrency"
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "orgPreferenceSettings" : {
            "notesReservedPref01": true,
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "chatterEnabled": true
        },
        "orderSettings" : {
            "enableOrders": true
        },
        "accountSettings" : {
            "enableAccountTeams": true,
            "showViewHierarchyLink": true
        },
        "nameSettings" : {
            "enableMiddleName": true
        },
        "forecastingSettings" : {
            "enableForecasts": true
        },
        "activitiesSettings" : {
            "enableSidebarCalendarShortcut": false,
            "showEventDetailsMultiUserCalendar": false
        },
        "knowledgeSettings" : {
            "enableKnowledge": false
        },
        "opportunitySettings" : {
            "enableOpportunityTeam": false
        }
    },
    "hasSampleData": "true",
    "language": "en_US",
    "country": "AU"
}
```

Any thoughts on how should I fix this? I tried to remove the enableKnowledge: false line but scratch org created successfully but knowledge is enabled.

Comment: This sounds like a bug; you should log a case with support.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for that. It does sound one to me. But I just want to confirm whether others have seeing this before

Comment: I'll give it a try today in my pre-release org and see what happens.

Comment: Just hit this issue again today. My feature list is completely different than yours so that doesn't look like the underlying issue. I'm guessing it's just enabled in all scratch orgs and cannot be removed. This is definitely still a bug.